# How to get the sent and received sms details programmatically in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sms, logging

I need to get the sms details from iPhone, that is count of sent and received messages and all messages that are stored in iPhone device. How can I implement them programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the current SDK supports functions to access SMS information as there is currently no API to get access to the user's SMS/MMS library.. I guess you can only do it for Jailbroken devices

Comment: Correct, in the official SDK your can only send a SMS. There is no way to read any received SMSes.